# set() funtion jumbles the order of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

This seems a bit odd! I did a program which required me removing duplicated from the list and choose the second last number. I did it using set(). however I came up with something unexpected.

```
set([32.0,36.0,39.0,40.0])
```

gives me an output of [32.0, 40.0, 36.0, 39.0]. I want to know why this happens. I'm using python 3.9.1
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't odd. This happens because set objects have no order, the order you get from iterating over a set is not guaranteed (it's arbitrary but consistent within a process). This is generally a property of hash-based containers, although python dict objects *do* maintain insertion order despite being hash-based

Comment: Is there any function of removing duplicates while keeping the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Python 3.7 or later you can use a dictionary instead of a set.

```
>>> l = [32.0,36.0,39.0,40.0]
>>> l[:] = list(dict.fromkeys(l))
>>> l
[32.0, 36.0, 39.0, 40.0]
```

The keys will be ordered by the order of insertion into the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([10,2,2,1,10,3,3]))
```